# "Error: '.class' expected"

Tags: java

So I'm new to Java, and my most recent piece of code has not worked. I get `error: not a statement` twice and `error: ';' expected` once.

If I try `radius=double;`, it appears with the error: `Error: '.class' expected` on line 8, where the caret shows under the semi-colon.

I am not sure what is wrong, but here is my code. It isn't long... thank-you in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math;

public class Formula {
    public static void main(String[] args);{
    double = radius;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Radius of circle (cm) :> ");
        double radius = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Area of circle :> " + Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
        System.out.print("Circumference of circle :> " + 2 * Math.PI * radius);
        System.out.print("Surface area the sphere with that radius :> " + 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
        System.out.print("Volume of sphere with that radius :> " + 4/3 * (radius * Math.pow(radius,2)));

    }
}
```

Comment: `double = radius` makes no sense.

Comment: What `double = radius;` is supposed to be?

Comment: There are a few things.  See the main has a `;` after it.  Take that out.  `double = radius;` is wrong  you need something different  perhaps something like `double radius;` OR `double radius = 0;`

Comment: 'double=radius;' was meant to allow 'double radius = in.nextDouble(); to make sense.

Comment: @buzzsawddog - I get "error: variable radius is already defined in method main(String[])" now.

Comment: Look at the answer from @Troubleshoot below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
double = radius;
```

to

```
double radius = 0;
```

and remove the `;` after the `public static void main(String[] args);` method definition.

**Also**, in the statement `double radius = in.nextDouble();` you will have to remove the `double` keyword, since you have already defined a variable with the same name.

Comment: Thankyou, this worked perfectly. I removed "double" and also added ".*" after "java.lang.Math" and it works.

Answer (score 3):

You have three problems with your code:

Remove the semi-colon on the declaration of the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Your second problem is that you do not have a reference for your double variable. All variables must have references. Consider your code which should be:

```
double radius = 0;
```

*double* is the data type and *radius* is the reference. In other words, double is the type of variable and radius is the name of the variable.

Your third problem is this line.

```
double radium = in.nextDouble();
```

You should change it to:

```
radius = in.nextDouble();
```

All variables must be correctly referenced. Also by declaring the variable again, you're shadowing the old one.

---

It would be better to instead of initializing the variable then initializing it again, delete your line:

```
double = radius
```

or if you changed it to what I said above, remove

```
double radius = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ';' from your main

```
public static void main(String[] args);
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: That is not the full answer.

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @ramonBoza you only answered part of the problem.

Comment: I know, but after me there were another replies with what left to mine, so i preffered not to "leech" that information :P

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declarations are confused: `double = radius;` doesn't make sense because `double` is a type, not a variable (and variable declarations look like `type identifier = value;` not `type = identifier;` or `identifier = type;`), and you declare but never use the `radium` variable. Should be something like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Radius of circle (cm) :> ");
double radius = in.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Area of circle :> " + Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
System.out.print("Circumference of circle :> " + 2 * Math.PI * radius);
System.out.print("Surface area the sphere with that radius :> " + 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
System.out.print("Volume of sphere with that radius :> " + 4/3 * (radius * Math.pow(radius,2)));
```

And you shouldn't have that `;` at the end of your `main` method declaration line.

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't expect such wonderful feedback so quickly. This was a pleasant surprise. ^^

Answer (score 0):

culprit (i.e. wrong way of declaring a variable):

> double = radius;

should be something of this form:

> double radius = 0;

However, I see you are using radius again, but this time correctly, to get the value entered by the user from the console, so you can safely delete the culprit statement and it should work.

Comment: May I ask why this is the wrong way of declaring a variable, and why "double radius = 0;" is correct?

Comment: It is just the formal syntax definition for declaring variables in Java. You can look at it as a rule "type identifier = value;". Also, declaring just "double radius;" would be considered correct as Java would automatically initialize the variable to 0.0. If you want to initialize yourself, then you can do so by declaring "double var = 0.0". Note that I initialize to 0.0 because it is a double. If I was to initialize just to 0, i.e. an int from Java's perspective, it would need to convert it to 0.0, i.e. a double. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math;

public class Formula
{
public static void main(String[] args);
{
double = radius;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Radius of circle (cm) :> ");
    double radius = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Area of circle :> " + Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
    System.out.print("Circumference of circle :> " + 2 * Math.PI * radius);
    System.out.print("Surface area the sphere with that radius :> " + 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
    System.out.print("Volume of sphere with that radius :> " + 4/3 * (radius * Math.pow(radius,2)));

    }
}
```

What it should look like :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math;

public class Formula
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

double radius = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Radius of circle (cm) :> ");
    radius = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Area of circle :> " + Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
    System.out.print("Circumference of circle :> " + 2 * Math.PI * radius);
    System.out.print("Surface area the sphere with that radius :> " + 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius,2));
    System.out.print("Volume of sphere with that radius :> " + 4/3 * (radius * Math.pow(radius,2)));

    }
}
```

You had a semicolon after your method, declaring a double needs to equal something, and you don't need to say **double radius = in.nextDouble();** you just need **radius = in.nextDouble();**